# Equivalence of p-values from Jonckheere-Terpstra test and Kendall's tau

Tags: p-value, kendall-tau, test-for-trend

I'm using the Jonckheere-Terpstra test to confirm whether an interval variable, distributed across five levels of an ordinal variable, display a significant trend. I'm using the *clinfun* package, developed for R.

The resulting JT statistic is 8965.5 and has a significance of around 0.02 (depending on the value I choose for the "nperm" parameter). I'm not sure how the "nperm" value should be determined. The author of the *clinfun* package used a value of 5000 in his example, so I've been trying similar values.

The value of Kendall's tau for the same two variables is 0.098 and has a significance of 0.08.

I'm aware that these two procedures (Jonckheere's test and Kendall's tau) are closely related. However, I have now stumbled upon a number of (perhaps unreliable) sources claiming that the two procedures should display identical p-values.

Should the p-values be identical, and if so, how can I accurately determine the significance of Jonckheere's test?

Thanks.

Comment: In SPSS, for example, p-value for Jonckheere-Terpstra is the same as p-value for Kendall's tau-b in `Nonparametric correlations` procedure, but is somewhat different from Kendall's tau (b or c) in `Crosstabs` procedure. One has to dig why it is so; it appears that tau's significance can be computed in different ways.

Comment: Yes, one of the examples I found reproduced the same value on SPSS (using Nonparametric correlations). Unfortunately I cannot validate my Jonckheere test result on SPSS, since that feature is not part of my SPSS subscription... Anyway, do you think it's worth worrying about the validity of the R Jonckheere test result?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't say anything about this test in `R`. In SPSS Algorithms document it must be described how p-value is found.

Comment: I have no answer to your question, but I'm interested in the way you calculate the significance of your JT statistics. Thanks!